# Create procedure error weekday()

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure, weekday

I only have to execute the procedure on mondays; so I first do a test on WEEKDAY() but there is a syntax error and I can't find out what is wrong?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fm_Upd_Histo_Inv`()
BEGIN
-- Test if it is Monday 
    CASE WEEKDAY(curdate()) = 0 then
        insert into db1w_histo_inventory (year, week, store, total, to_do)
            select year(curdate()),
                WEEKOFYEAR(curdate()),
                S.store, 
                count(S.INVDATE) as TotalToDo,
                sum(datediff(curdate(), S.INVDATE) > '365') as 'TO_DO'
            from mrqr_stock S
            left join mrqr_organisms O
                on O.ORGANISM = S.STORE
            where (O.ORGANISM like '01%'
                        or O.ORGANISM like 'VV%'
                        or O.ORGANISM like 'IK%')
            group by S.STORE
    end;
END
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use. Add the related tag

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is usually used in statements like select, insert, update, delete. It is not used for control flow. Use `IF` instead. And set a different delimiter.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fm_Upd_Histo_Inv`()
BEGIN
-- Test if it is Monday 
    IF WEEKDAY(curdate()) = 0 then
        insert into db1w_histo_inventory (year, week, store, total, to_do)
            select year(curdate()),
                WEEKOFYEAR(curdate()),
                S.store, 
                count(S.INVDATE) as TotalToDo,
                sum(datediff(curdate(), S.INVDATE) > '365') as 'TO_DO'
            from mrqr_stock S
            left join mrqr_organisms O
                on O.ORGANISM = S.STORE
            where (O.ORGANISM like '01%'
                        or O.ORGANISM like 'VV%'
                        or O.ORGANISM like 'IK%')
            group by S.STORE
    end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```